# Azure Functions Pre-Compiled F# CosmosDBTrigger Environmental Configuration

Tags: azure-functions

I have worked on an Event Store of sorts using Azure Functions with F#.  There were some challenges in getting everything working as expected across the different Function App deployments (I'm having different parts of the chain essentially working and communicating with different functions over HTTP and Cosmos DB Triggers).

I've done a fair amount of refactoring, as well as separation of logic with config values, but I cannot seem to find a way to rely solely on the configuration for a few values that I would prefer not to hard-code.

Particularly here the **DatabaseName** and the **CollectionName**.  Even when I set the values from Configuration, it still requires me to hardocode the values.

```
[<FunctionName("streamEventDataTrigger")>]
let CosmosStreamEventDataTrigger
    ([< CosmosDBTrigger ("store", "events", //Figure out how to pull this from Configuration *RIGHT NOW IT IS HARD-CODE
        DatabaseName = "FC_EventStoreDatabaseName",
        CollectionName =  "FC_EventCollectionName",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "FC_CosmosDBConnectionString",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true )>] 
        documents: IReadOnlyList<Document>)
    (log : ILogger) = async {
            documents
            |> Cosmos.processDocumentFeed
            |> EventProjector.projectEntries            
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
            |> StreamInterface.writer
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
            |> ignore } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

*I am not using any other kind of binding json file or anything.  This is all compiled and published via zip file.*

This is not urgent or critical, but will remain an annoying aspect for me if unaddressed, and I figured others may've encountered this and have answers on how to address this.

Comment: First, be sure you set the Configuration correctly. Considering your Function was compiled and published via zip file, you can try setting the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` to ***Configuration***, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization  You can upload your error message so people can help you better.

Comment: The set accessor of DatabaseName and CollectionName is been setted to inaccessible by the designer. Source code didn't do anything, that is why you can not get settings from configuration. This is by designed.

Comment: @DorisLv,  This was helpful to highlight and it comes up for me in another context; however, just to be clear, everything except these two fields has been working correctly for me. So this wasn't the particular issue here.  It seems as highlighted by the other  answer/comment that what I'm trying to do is not possible by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code, you can see the designer's intention here:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Description;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB;

namespace Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.ReturnValue)]
    [Binding]
    public sealed class CosmosDBAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CosmosDBAttribute()
        {
        }

        public CosmosDBAttribute(string databaseName, string collectionName)
        {
            DatabaseName = databaseName;
            CollectionName = collectionName;
        }

        [AutoResolve]
        public string DatabaseName { get; private set; }

        [AutoResolve]
        public string CollectionName { get; private set; }

        public bool CreateIfNotExists { get; set; }

        [ConnectionString]
        public string ConnectionStringSetting { get; set; }

        [AutoResolve]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [AutoResolve]
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

        public int CollectionThroughput { get; set; }

        [AutoResolve(ResolutionPolicyType = typeof(CosmosDBSqlResolutionPolicy))]
        public string SqlQuery { get; set; }

        public bool UseMultipleWriteLocations { get; set; }

        public bool UseDefaultJsonSerialization { get; set; }

        [AutoResolve]
        public string PreferredLocations { get; set; }

        internal SqlParameterCollection SqlQueryParameters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see from this code, WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB doesn't want to do any processing on these two values in source code, it even cannot use the set method. The other values are set to the values of the corresponding environment variables. the set accessor is been setted to inaccessible, this is by designed.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been set as inaccessible by design as it does force me to keep something hard-coded that feels like I should be able to configure it outside the code as I would want to potentially keep different DB and Collection names in different deployment contexts.   However, this is helpful to know and clear to see that since these are inaccessible, there doesn't seem to be any reasonable way to address this objective I have that would be worth pursuing... that I can think of now.